# In Meteor, how to append the app's root url to the image path dynamically?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Let's say I have an image in the folder `public/images/avatar.svg`. I can use this in css or in an img tag by saying `/images/avatar.svg`. But I need to pass the image's full url to a third party service (Gravatar). In rails, we can append the root url of the app dynamically so that when in development, it will be `http://localhost:3000/images/avatar.svg` and in production it will be `http://www.myapp.com/images/avatar.svg`. Can we do this in Meteor?

Comment: Have you tried [Meteor.absoluteUrl()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl)? If you're using it lots in templates it would be worth creating a global helper that calls the method so you can use it like `<img src="{{absoluteUrl '/images/avatar.svg'}}">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the return value of `Meteor.absoluteUrl('images/avatar.svg')` to your third party service.

**Note**: Do not include the leading `/` that you would generally use when referring to the image within your application.

You can read more [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl) for other options.